# googletest global environment

Tags: installation, environment, googletest, teardown

I'm trying to set up a global environment using ::testing::Environment. I have 28 tests witch all create 28 clients and 28 servers and I want to have only one client and one server. I don't know if I should use ::Environment or ::Test with shared resources.

Comment: What you are describing is against test in separation principle. Are you sure? Do you have some performance reasons?

Comment: My program create a client and server for every test and I want to use the same client and server because this is time consuming. And I've read that I can do it with ::testing::Environment

Comment: Ok - understood - but I'd do it differently. I'd define C++ interface class for client and servers - in production code - use real implementation of server/client; in UT - use mocked version - see [googlemock].

Comment: I can't because my manager imposed to me to use gtest and I've already have a set of tests that I have to modify in such way that it uses only one client and one server. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].